# Disk errors on tty and syslog/dmesg

Tags: 11.04, disk, tty

Recently I have started to get a lot of these errors:

```
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.554292] ata5: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.559346] sr 4:0:0:0: CDB: Test Unit Ready: 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.560191] ata5.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.560231]          res 51/20:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x40 (internal error)
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.575310] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.579801] ata5: hard resetting link
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.929320] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.941936] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jun 18 08:57:42 abacus kernel: [  401.969426] ata5: EH complete
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.527699] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 action 0x6
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.527779] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.527822] ata5: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.527901] sr 4:0:0:0: CDB: Test Unit Ready: 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.528103] ata5.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.528142]          res 51/20:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x40 (internal error)
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.528184] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.528303] ata5: hard resetting link
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.875894] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.888267] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jun 18 08:57:54 abacus kernel: [  413.916365] ata5: EH complete
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.537834] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 action 0x6
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.545253] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.549788] ata5: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.554840] sr 4:0:0:0: CDB: Test Unit Ready: 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.555201] ata5.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.555242]          res 51/20:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x40 (internal error)
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.570483] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.574695] ata5: hard resetting link
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.924954] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.936831] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jun 18 08:57:56 abacus kernel: [  415.965001] ata5: EH complete
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.529784] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x40 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x80800 action 0x6
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.529904] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.530023] ata5: SError: { HostInt 10B8B }
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.530104] sr 4:0:0:0: CDB: Test Unit Ready: 00 00 00 00 00 00
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.530425] ata5.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.530466]          res 51/20:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x40 (internal error)
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.530583] ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.530705] ata5: hard resetting link
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.873218] ata5: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.885040] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jun 18 08:58:02 abacus kernel: [  421.913404] ata5: EH complete
```

Are these critical error messages? What would be the cause and remedy?

Here is the smartctl data:

```
smartctl 5.40 2010-07-12 r3124 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-10 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Momentus 5400.6 series
Device Model:     ST9640320AS
Serial Number:    5WX1W9PW
Firmware Version: 0002HPM1
User Capacity:    640,135,028,736 bytes
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4
Local Time is:    Fri Jul  1 08:08:47 2011 PKT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:         (   0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 161) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x103f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   112   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       45873136
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       208
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   076   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       4339126852
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3132
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       208
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       19
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   059   044   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 41 (0 3 46 33)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1915
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   041   056   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (0 13 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   048   047   000    Old_age   Always       -       45873136
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3115         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      2865         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Perhaps your disk is broken. Can you check your S.M.A.R.T. information by installing `smartmontools` and run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` (replace `/dev/sda` by your disk) ?

Comment: added to main post, have a look, i have no idea what those numbers mean :D

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you  may have some buggy drive firmware or a defective drive.  It wouldn't hurt to run the long SMART selftest.  You can use smartctl or the disk utility gui to do so.  You may also want to download and run Seagate's drive diagnostics tool.  If it says there is a problem with the drive, then they should replace it under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the seek and raw read errors are not critical, maybe just annoying. There is nothing you can do about it except replace the drive.

For more info and explanation on the SMART data [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.).

If the errors started to appear after a kernel update, it might be worth booting into an older kernel and check the logs there.